# Ubuntu's sudden root storage volume is full ( 20.04 )

Tags: 20.04, root, storage

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 as a dual boot, for the third time when I turned on the system, the system did not enter the desktop anymore;  After restarting it twice, it entered the desktop and the page opened that the root is very full (notably, I allocated 40G to root and 160G to home).

I went back to version 20.04; Exactly the same problem was created.

The output that can be seen on the desktop:

[image]

I ran the following command:

```
lsblk
```

Result:

[image]

I ran the following command:(The first two content commands delete the log files
,Commands 3 and 4 are for restarting syslog and limiting the volume of log recording by journallog)

```
echo "" > /var/log/kern.log
echo "" > /var/log/syslog
service syslog restart
journalctl --vacuum-size=50M
```

I run the above commands and the logs are deleted, but the volume of the root goes from 20G to 39G live.  (The error still remains)

[image]

Now we apply the following command:

```
sudo demsg --level warn,err
```

Output in the desktop terminal:

```
[[  259.443633] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, 
type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443634] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443635] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.443715] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443717] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443719] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.443741] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443742] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443743] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.443753] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443755] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443756] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.443781] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443782] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443784] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.443793] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443795] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443796] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.443820] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443822] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443823] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.443833] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443834] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443836] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.443860] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443861] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443863] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.443872] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443874] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443876] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.443955] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.443956] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.443957] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444002] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444003] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444004] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444016] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444018] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444019] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444032] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444033] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444034] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444047] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444047] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444048] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444059] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444060] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444061] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444072] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444073] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444074] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444120] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444121] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444122] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444145] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444146] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444147] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444160] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444161] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444162] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444185] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444186] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444187] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444199] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444200] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444201] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444225] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444225] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444239] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444239] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444240] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444264] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444265] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444279] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444280] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444281] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444295] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444295] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444308] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444309] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444310] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444322] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444323] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444324] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444337] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444337] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444338] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444351] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444352] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444353] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444365] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444366] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444367] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444379] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444380] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444381] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444394] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444395] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444396] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444415] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444416] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444417] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444429] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444430] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444431] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444443] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444444] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444445] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444457] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444458] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444459] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444472] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444472] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444473] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444486] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444487] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444488] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444501] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444502] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444503] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444515] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444516] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444517] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444528] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444529] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444530] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444542] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444543] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444544] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444556] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444557] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444558] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444581] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444582] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444583] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444596] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444597] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444598] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444621] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444622] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444635] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444636] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444637] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444661] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444662] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444663] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444675] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444676] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444677] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444700] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444701] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444702] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444716] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444717] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444718] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444740] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444741] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444742] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444754] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444755] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444756] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444769] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444770] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444771] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444784] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444784] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444785] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444797] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444798] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444799] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444812] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444813] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444814] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444826] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444827] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444828] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444840] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444841] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444842] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444854] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444855] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444856] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444868] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444869] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444870] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444890] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444891] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444892] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444904] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444905] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444906] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444920] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444922] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444923] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444933] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444935] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444936] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444948] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444949] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444951] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444963] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444964] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444965] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444976] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444977] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444979] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.444991] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.444993] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.444994] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445014] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445015] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445017] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445042] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445043] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445044] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445056] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445057] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445059] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445070] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445071] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445073] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445092] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445094] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445095] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445106] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445108] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445109] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445120] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445121] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445123] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445133] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445135] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445136] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445149] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445150] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445152] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445164] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445165] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445176] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445178] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445191] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445192] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445213] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445226] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445228] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445242] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445243] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445245] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445256] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445257] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445259] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445269] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445270] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445284] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445299] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445300] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445311] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445312] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445334] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445335] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445348] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445362] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445363] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445365] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445377] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445390] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445392] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445405] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445406] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
[  259.445408] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[  259.445418] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[  259.445420] pcieport 0000:00:1b.0:   device [8086:a3e9] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
]
```

Output in system bias: (recovery mode)

[image]

What can I do to solve the problem forever?

Comment: Seems the problem might be related to the [Realtek RTL8188EE](https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/problem-with-realtek-rtl8188ee-wireless-adapter-and-r8168/19034) - this is the exact same error message. Hopefully this could get someone else on track with some more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://itsfoss.com/pcie-bus-error-severity-corrected/ there is a possibility that there exist some compatibility issues with your kernel and the hardware.

The kernel uses a special Advanced Error Reporting for telling you about these issues, but it can be turned off with a GRUB option. What you need to do is:

1. Make a backup of GRUB configuration:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/original.grub
```

2. Next open the GRUB configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

3. Find the following line and add the option `pci=noaer`, so that it reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"
```

You may have other options on said line already, in which case just append the option.
4. Remember to update the GRUB configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

You need to purge the files like you already did before, and then try to boot the system up again to see whether it helps.